# Call a base abstract method in an override of that method

Tags: c#, methods, abstract

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637939/calling-a-base-abstract-method-in-an-override-of-that-method) this link that is similar to my question but still I can't seem to understand something.

```
public abstract class ClassA
{
     protected abstract void Method()
     {
        //some logic here
     }
}

public class ClassB : ClassA
{
     protected override void Method()
     {
          base.Method();
          // some custom logic here
     }
}
```

This is my case and I can't seem to find out why I'm unable to call `base.Method()` from the overridden method in ClassB. The error says: "cannot call an abstract base method". If I can't call it why is the functionality of filling and abstract base method with logic even there? Can please somebody explain to me what is the mistake I make and how can I fix it?

Comment: An abstract method can't have a body. Make it virtual.

Comment: You can't give an abstract method a body, why do you think that you can?

Comment: Your code would not compile. Abstract methods cannot have bodies.

Comment: okay thanks for the immediate answers, so as for the downvotes I will know not to ask stupid questions from now on, if you can downvote some more I might learn faster :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the C# spec:

> An abstract method is a virtual method with no implementation. An
>   abstract method is declared with the abstract modifier and is
>   permitted only in a class that is also declared abstract. An abstract
>   method must be overridden in every non-abstract derived class.

So an abstract method cannot be implemented. The abstract method therefore cannot have a body:

```
protected abstract void Method();
```

If you want some default logic in the base class, you must declare the method `virtual`:

```
protected virtual void Method()
{
    //some logic here
}
```

Comment: I don't know if your quote refers to the latest spec, but "An abstract method must be overridden in every non-abstract derived class." is not quite exact corresponding to the current (2021) behavior: Its body must be *defined* in every derived non-abstract class. This definition may occur in the first non-abstract derived class in the class hierarchy _or in any abstract class above_ the first non-abstract derived class.

Answer (score 4):

The keyword [`abstract`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5.aspx) means that deriving classes must implement the method, but abstract class itself does not provide any implementation (thus the error).

I think you might be looking for [`virtual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4.aspx) which both provides some functionality at the base level and allows implementing classes to override the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

From the [MSDN Website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664435%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> It is a compile-time error for a base-access ([Section 7.5.8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691362%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)) to
>   reference an abstract method. In the example

```
abstract class A 
{    
    public abstract void F();
}

class B: A 
{   
    public override void F() 
    {
        base.F(); // Error, base.F is abstract
    }
}
```

> a compile-time error is reported for the `base.F()` invocation because
>   it references an abstract method.